# JavaFX compiling but nodes not appearing in application

Tags: java, javafx

Whenever I create a JavaFX program, it compiles fine, and everything is in order, until I get to running the application. When I do, the stage still shows, however none of the added nodes appear, only a white box. I've included a simple program I've made to demonstrate this:

```
package javafxfixing;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;

public class JavaFXFixing extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Button btNew = new Button("Press Me!");

        pane.getChildren().add(btNew);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("New program");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

This code compiles fine, but when I go to run it, the button is not shown in my window. I really hope I'm not missing something really obvious but I've coded JavaFX programs in this same manner and never had this happen until now.

Comment: Works fine for me.  What are you seeing?  Is the window showing up at all?  Have you tried running the same class on different machines?

Comment: @VGR when I run the application, a very small window appears with a white background, about the size the button would be. When resized, the white space stays where it is and the rest of the background is black. I've not tried any other machines. I've been doing some work with my graphics drivers, but to the extent of what I know nothing that would affect JavaFX

Comment: It sounds like your button is there but invisible somehow.  The pane will resize to the buttons size.  Try adding `btNew.setOnAction(e->System.out.println("It works"));` to see if it's there but maybe the colors are wrong.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  Using the latest version is a good idea.  And I would use a subclass of Pane, rather than Pane, so the button will be laid out properly.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I'm going to reset my computer, as this wasn't the only problem that's come up. I was running JDK 1.8.0 101 and JRE 1.8.0 111 with netbeans 8.1. I've also tried using a gridpane and hbox, both with comparable success (or lack therof)

Comment: @brian the nodes are indeed invisible. I've set the button to print an output and it does, so I'm not quite sure how to undo this. I've completely reset my computer to fix some other problems so it shouldn't be because of some leftover setting change. Any ideas?

Comment: All I can think of is maybe the css is screwed up.  Maybe try `btn.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:black;")`

Comment: I've used setStyle to configure the button, and nothing happened. I decided to dig a little more and found a javaFX tab under Tools -> Options -> Java -> JavaFX. Nothing in there seemed to help, so I'm stuck again. I'll keep looking for javaFX options to see if there's anything I can change to help.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, the issue is resolved. I've spent the last few weeks reinstalling drivers, formatting, refreshing, etc. and somewhere in the process it has fixed my javaFX. Not sure what caused the problems but it may have been something to do with my computer having Optimus video drivers which is what caused several of the other problems I was facing at the same time.